# $(\beth_{\omega})^\omega=\beth_{\omega+1}$

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

I'm trying to show that $(\beth_{\omega})^\omega=2^{\beth_\omega}$. This is an exercise in Kunen where he suggests to encode subsets of $\beth_\omega$ with functions from $\omega\rightarrow\beth_\omega$. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Cody

Comment: Can you give the *exact* reference, not just "Kunen"?

Comment: Oops, let me try that comment again.   This is Exercise I.13.33 in the 2013 edition of Kunen's *Set Theory*. It actually asks you to show a little more: $(\beth_\omega)^\omega = \left|\prod_{n < \omega} \beth_n\right| = \beth_{\omega+1}$.

Answer (score 6):

First, note that $(A\cap\beth_n)_{n<\omega}$ is a function $f_A:\omega\to\bigcup_n\mathcal P(\beth_n)$, and that the assignment $A\mapsto f_A$ is 1-1.

Then, note that $\mathcal P(\beth_n)$ is in bijection with $\beth_{n+1}$. Fix bijections for each $n$, and use them to replace $f_A$ into a function that takes ordinal values.

Comment: Aww. I just came up with that myself. :)

Comment: I am slightly confused about SCH and this question, actually. Does that mean that SCH cannot fail at $\beth_\omega$?

Comment: Asaf: SCH can fail at $\beth_\omega$; in fact, we can have GCH below $\aleph_\omega$, and $\mathcal P(\aleph_\omega)$ big. Remember, SCH is equivalent to asserting that, for all $\kappa$, we have $\kappa^{\mbox{cf}(\kappa)}=\kappa^{+}+2^{\mbox{cf}(\kappa)}$; it does not assert a separation between $\gimel(\kappa)$ and $2^\kappa$.

Comment: Yes, I knew that SCH could fail at $\aleph_\omega$ which is why it was a bit strange for me. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: By the way, regarding the failure of SCH at $\aleph_\omega$ do we know how far we can blow up $\aleph_\omega^\omega$ while we do that? (Obviously not above $\aleph_{\omega_4}$, but anything else?)

Comment: The best we know is how to make ${\aleph_\omega}^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_{\alpha+1}$, for any infinite $\alpha<\omega_1$ we want. It is open whether we can get past $\aleph_{\omega_1}$.